# salat in jamat and how to complete in tahaya

Tags: sunni

when we join late in jamat and w sit with imam till he ends prayer, and we have to get up for completion of salat ,during tahaya o we read Darood and dua aftr darood also or w keep silent after tashad .

Answer (score -1):

If you joined the Imaam during the sitting, before salaam, you're to pray at-tahyatul without the darood and the du'a.

Once the Imaam finishes the prayer, you stand up and complete whatever number of rak'at you have to do.

Keep in mind, if you joined the imaam in fourth rak'at, it will be your first because that's when you started, and you have to complete the rest.